# Code in establishing a connection in MySQL database

Tags: java, mysql

I'm trying to establish a connection to my database (MySQL) and I have searched a code online that looks like this, but what he uses is an Oracle database, not a MySQL database which is what I have used.
Can somebody help? This is my code...

```
public static Connection DB()
{
    try {
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"); //This is my problem
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Image","root","");
        return con;
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
    return null;
}
```

[This is the image of my error message.][1]

Comment: change the `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")`

Comment: Here is the link for mysql connectivity https://www.javatpoint.com/example-to-connect-to-the-mysql-database

Comment: The duplicate contains a lot of information on how to connect to MySQL. Be careful, some might be outdated, so read the comments too.

Comment: The current documentation contains good examples and is located here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-usagenotes-connect-drivermanager.html#connector-j-examples-connection-drivermanager

Comment: The next time you're searching online you might want to *keep searching* if the first one isn't what you're looking for. There are hundreds of examples on how to connect to MySQL, so it's ridiculous that you chose one that connects to Oracle.

Comment: Remember a java Class file can be decompiled with a Java decompiler which exposes your MySQL username and password.. So if this is a public program you better off making a webinterface on a other server which talks with the SQL server. And use a protocol like REST, SOAP, XML-RPC, JSON to talk between the Java program and the webinterface

Answer (score 0):

replace this

```
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");  
Connection 
con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Image","root","");
```

with this

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");  
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(  
"jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Image","username","password");
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");  
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Image","root","");
```

Comment: You should explain your answer and why it is correct not just post code.